# Gunzip all the files present in source directory in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, gunzip

I have written a code to gunzip all the files present in the source folder. But I want to include the check that if gunzipped file doesn't exist then gunzip it else move to next file.

```
source_dir = "/Users/path"
dest_dir = "/Users/path/Documents/path"


for src_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.gz')):

    base = os.path.basename(src_name)
    dest_name = os.path.join(dest_dir, base[:-3])
    with: gzip.open(src_name, 'rb') as infile, open(dest_name, 'wb') as outfile:
            try:
                for line in infile:
                    print ("outfile: %s" %outfile)
                    if not os.path.exists(dest_name):
                      outfile.write(line)
                      print( "converted: %s" %dest_name) 

            except EOFError:
                print("End of file error occurred.")

            except Exception:
                print("Some error occurred.")
```

I have used `os.path.exist` to check whether the file exists or not, but it seems like `os.path.exist` doesn't work here.

Comment: For problem 2, use your OS's scheduled job utilities. No need to try to program your own.

Comment: There is no question in part 1. Part 2 is way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I want to add a check if gunzipped file doesn't exist then only gunzip it other wise move to next file. How to check this?

Comment: I suggest that you ask two separate questions. For part 1, you would use `os.path.exists` or similar. Browse through the docs for the `os.path` module.

Comment: Also, use a single `with`: `with open(...) as infile, open(...) as outfile:`. Saves a level of nesting and makes the code look cleaner.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I used `os.path.exists`, but its not working(not able to check whether file is gunzipped or not). You can see in my code, this line is commented.

Comment: "It does not work" does not help me help you. Here is what you need to do: remove part 2, ask it in a separate question so it does not drag this one into getting closed. Describe what you did exactly and why and how it did not work. Post any errors you encountered and describe any unexpected results in detail.

Comment: Also, that commented line is in a **very** weird place

Comment: Please do not take my nagging personally. I think your question has a lot of potential, and you clearly put some work into it and the code it is about. I just want to guide you into asking a high quality, specific question, which it currently is not.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Where should I place it then? It was indented earlier like below:   `if not os.path.exists(dest_name):
                    outfile.write(line)
                    print( "converted: %s" %dest_name)`

Comment: Start by fixing the things I asked you and then I will draft a full answer for you, with a nice explanation of the whys and wherefores. When you explain to me what it was doing wrong and how you know it was wrong in detail, and remove part2, we can talk.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I have made changes to it. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. Can you add a *detailed* explanation of what you mean by "but it seems like os.path.exist doesn't work here"? What do you see that leads you to believe it does not work?

Comment: I've retracted my close vote BTW. I've drafted a response, but I want you to tell me why you think the check does not work in your own words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misplaced the `path.exists` call. It should be:

```
source_dir = "/Users/path"
dest_dir = "/Users/path/Documents/path"


for src_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.gz')):

    base = os.path.basename(src_name)
    dest_name = os.path.join(dest_dir, base[:-3])

    if not os.path.exists(dest_name):
        with gzip.open(src_name, 'rb') as infile, open(dest_name, 'wb') as outfile:
            try:
                for line in infile:
                    print("outfile: %s" % outfile)
                    outfile.write(line)
                    print("converted: %s" % dest_name)

            except EOFError:
                print("End of file error occurred.")

            except Exception:
                print("Some error occurred.")
```

Also as @MadPhysicist emphasized:
"doing the check after open(..., 'wb') (as you did in your original code), will always say that the file exists because that is what open(..., 'w') does"

On top of that even if you made some other check for the necessity of gunzipping, doing it where you've put it will do the check on every line, which is completely redundant as the result will be the same for all lines (exists/not-exists).

Comment: I didn't change the existing code much, just gave an example of how to use setup the list of files that he needed. All I did is add 5 lines before the for_loop. Which originally did not provide what he wanted.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Didn't see OP's question changed at first. fixed my answer, misplaced if statement. Please re-check and give your thoughts.

Comment: You may want to add a note explaining that doing the check after `open(..., 'wb')` will always say that the file exists because that what `open(..., 'w')` does. That means the file will be truncated but never written, whether it existed or not originally.

Comment: Thanks, @MadPhysicist for giving such a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ronemiller.

Comment: NP, don't forget to accept if this indeed solves the issue.